# Best way to serve static JS, CSS, etc. files over https in Azure

Tags: azure

I am creating a plugin for an existing web application, which expects me to serve a bunch of static HTML/JS/CSS/etc over a secure https connection.

I have just signed up an Azure account for this. Can someone tell me what are the next steps I should take to get things setup correctly?

Thanks

Comment: Are you going to be serving this from an App Service Web App? If so, by default you can serve content over https using Microsoft's cert. Just go to https://[your site name].azurewebsites.net/[path to your static content].

Comment: Since this is all static content, I don't think this has to be a Web App, unless there is any benefit to it, that I am not aware?

Comment: No, I just assumed you were already serving your web application from a Web App. EvilSnobu's answer below is spot on.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just drop those files in [Azure Blob Storage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/storage-create-storage-account) (think object-store or Amazon S3-like). It's **HTTPS**-enabled by default.

```bash
$ curl -v https://{storage-account}.blob.core.windows.net

Server certificate:
*        subject: CN=*.blob.core.windows.net
*        start date: 2016-07-02 05:15:10 GMT
*        expire date: 2018-05-07 17:03:30 GMT
*        issuer: C=US; ST=Washington; L=Redmond; O=Microsoft Corporation;
                 OU=Microsoft IT; CN=Microsoft IT SSL SHA2
```

You can use [Microsoft Azure Storage Explorer](http://storageexplorer.com/) to upload your static content with zero fussing around. Alternatively, [use the SDK for a programatic approach](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/storage-dotnet-how-to-use-blobs).

[Azure CDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cdn/cdn-create-new-endpoint) is one additional service to consider on top of Blob storage, especially if your clients are geographically spread out. They'll get better performance (throughput) and lower latency (edge caching).

**LATER UPDATE:**
A static website feature is now available in Blob Storage -

[image: enable static website]

This gives you default document handling (AKA you browse to / and it serves `index.html`).

Upload your web assets to the `$web` container that was created as a part of static website enablement. You can do this directly in Azure Portal or via Azure Storage clients.

Comment: Azure blobs don't support a "default" object, so unless someone goes directly to something like `domain-name.com/default.html` or `domain-name.com/index.html`, this technique won't work.

Comment: Correct. But since "already existing web app" was mentioned, blob storage is applicable (i.e. with `<img src="...">` tags).. Wouldn't hurt for Azure Storage to support a default file, but i understand that's outside its scope.

Comment: Ah - that is true. I was thinking this was responding to the notion of deploying a static website to blob storage (which, without a default target, doesn't really work).